# In selenium.py, How to deal with 404 status code

Tags: python, selenium

I'm writing a selenium script by python. Something that I found out, is that when selenium gets 404 status code. it crashes. What is the best way to deal with it?

Comment: Have you tried using try-except structure to catch the exception??

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Sometimes a server we were using (i.e., not the main server we were testing, only a "sub-server") throughout our tests would crash. I added a minor sanity test to see if the server is up or not before the main tests ran. That is, I performed a simple GET request to the server, surrounded it with try-catch and if that passed I continue with the tests. Let me stress out this point- before i even started selenium i would perform a GET request using python's urllib2. It's not the best of solutions but it's fast it was enough for me.